# How to insert divs into div that text would go inline with it

Tags: html, css, css-position, inline

I have main page template which at the moment has such code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lrv11sean6y15se/index_backup.txt (I cant add code here in post somehow)

and looks like this:
[image]

***** First question appears hear, how to make [[Description]] text be 10px far from left div border?**

Then I have a part which I want to insert to this page which has such code:

```
<div style="text-align:center; width: 324px; color: #ffffff; background-color:#6b8861; font-size : 34px;">[[Title]]</div>
<div style="border:1px dotted #6b8861; text-align:center; width: 324px; color: #6b8861; background-color:#ffffff; font-size : 34px;">[[Picture1]]</div>
```

And looks like this:
[image]

I want that this part would nicely appear in right side of the div in which is text "[[Description]]". I have to mentioned that this text will be changed to much longer text and that part which I want to insert should be inline with all the text and look something like this:

[image]

I tried with display inline, and other methods, but all they disort my template totally and I reach the point where no one can help me and just tells me to not use inline and learn other ways. So guys I would like you to share your methods how could I do this.

Comment: post your code html and css

Comment: Somehow I cant add the code to the post: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lrv11sean6y15se/index_backup.txt

Answer (score 0):

**First question**
style="margin-left:10px"

Comment: if I have margin: 0 auto; how should it be changed to add left parameter? P.s. I updated the post

Answer (score 0):

It should work perfectly if the code flow is like this

```
.wrapper{position:relative; width:100%; overflow:auto}
.descrptn{display:inline-block; background:#fbffe2; float:left; margin-left:10px; width:60%}
.right{display:inline-block;  margin:0 10px; float:right}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z8zeM/1/)**

---

**Updated according to the origina code**

you need to order your divs properly which means there should be a parent div for all child divs.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="header"> 
<a href="www.one.lt"> <img border="0" src="http://www.gvcdigital.co.uk/images/graphic/header.png" width="985" height="96" alt="header" title="DigiSpot eBay store" /></a>
</div>

<div class="nav_menu"> 
<img border="0" src="http://www.gvcdigital.co.uk/images/graphic/meniu.png" alt="DigiSpot meniu" width="985" height="41" usemap="#mapas" />
  <map name="mapas">
    <area shape="rect" coords="56,0,0,41" href="www.one.lt" alt="DigiSpot eBay store home" title="DigiSpot eBay store home">
    <area shape="rect" coords="539,0,400,41" href="www.one.lt" alt="About Digispot" title="About DigiSpot">
    <area shape="rect" coords="699,0,539,41" href="www.one.lt" alt="Delivery information" title="Delivery information">
    <area shape="rect" coords="845,0,699,41" href="www.one.lt" alt="Returns information" title="Returns information">
    <area shape="rect" coords="985,0,845,41" href="www.one.lt" alt="Contacts information" title="Contacts information">
  </map>
</div>

<div class="desc"><img border="0" src="http://www.gvcdigital.co.uk/images/graphic/description.png" width="232" height="81"></div>

<!--Contaent starts-->
<div class="content">
<div class="left_panel">Lorem ipsum .</div>
<div class="right_panel">
  <div style="text-align:center; width: 324px; color: #ffffff; background-color:#6b8861; font-size : 34px;">[[Title]]</div>
  <div style="border:1px dotted #6b8861; text-align:center; width: 324px; background-color:#ffffff;">[[Picture1]]</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--Contaent ends-->
<div class="footer"><img border="0" src="graphic/buttom.png" width="524" height="42"></div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    color: #25670c;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    font-family : Times New Roman;
    font-size : 14px;
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper{width:1000px; margin:0 auto}
.header{height: 96px; width: 985px; margin: 0 auto;}
.nav-menu{
    height: 41px; width: 985px; margin: 0 auto;
}
.desc{width: 985px; height:81px; text-align: center; background-color:#d6d6a4;margin: 0 auto;}
.content{position:relative; width: 985px; overflow:auto}
.left_panel{ background:#fbffe2; float:left; margin-left:20px; width:600px; text-align:left}
.right_panel {

    text-align: left;
    background-color: #d6d6a4;
    margin: 0 auto; float:right
}
.footer {
    text-align: center;
    width: 985px;
    background-color: #d6d6a4;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**[DEMO UPDATED](http://jsfiddle.net/t5gC3/2/)**

Comment: @Tautvydas fiddle doesnt contain your entire code. that is just a showcase

Comment: I tried your code and It got wrong: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z6omeg7ragvae63/index_backup2.html If you can take a look

Comment: The problem is I cant use .css file or <style> because this template will be displayed inside other site (thats why I define css in style=""). I will not be able to edit template outside <body> borders. Second thing, its still is not as it suposed to be :( Maybe I did something wrong, here's mine updated one more time by your new code file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u16k7rybn54on8e/index2.html